# ArcPy Data Access Insert Cursor not writing geometries to feature class?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, geometry, cursor, pyscripter

I'm using PyScripter and running ArcGIS 10.2.1.

I am having troubles with the Insert Cursor in the arcpy module.

I have an empty feature class in my geodatabase and have created the short script below to try and find the issue, but have not been able to. When I run the script, it executes fine, but when I look in the attribute table of the feature class afterwards it is still empty.

```
import arcpy

fc = r"C:\Users\djh\Desktop\topo_map\test.gdb\well_location"
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@XY"])
xy = (206901.75, 5997594.47)

cursor.insertRow([xy])
```

I have copied this script straight from the "writing geometries" page on the ArcGIS help website, so I don't think it's a problem with syntax. Please let me know if there's a way to get around this issue.

Comment: If the table is open when you do this, you will see nothing since the table doesn't get updated until it is reopened

Comment: @Dan Patterson I only have PyScripter open when I run the script. I then open ArcMap, add the feature class, and open the attribute table, and it is still empty.

Comment: Hmmmm http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001v000000  try using the alternative of creating a Point object rather than using the SHAPE@XY method and see if that works

Comment: I tried the alternative (using a combination of arcpy.Point, arcpy.PointGeometry, and arcpy.CopyFeatures_management) and it now appears in the table. So this solves the issue, although I wonder why the Insert Cursor wasn't working. In any case, thanks very much for you help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PyScripter is somewhat lax with object lifetimes and will keep stuff around after it's run. Use the `with` statement to ensure you close the edit session.

```
import arcpy

fc = r"C:\Users\djh\Desktop\topo_map\test.gdb\well_location"
xy = (206901.75, 5997594.47)

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@XY"]) as cursor:
    cursor.insertRow([xy])
```

Answer (score 4):

Using IDLE, I ran your test using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop, immediately after a reboot (by coincidence) so there should be nothing laying around from previous tests.  The code is identical to the third example at [Writing Geometries](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001v000000), and I agree with you that the point does not get written.

I believe that part of the documentation is in error and that instead you should use the following which I tested successfully.

```
import arcpy

fc = r"C:\Users\djh\Desktop\topo_map\test.gdb\well_location"
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@XY"])
xy = arcpy.Point(206901.75, 5997594.47)

cursor.insertRow([xy])
```

As @JasonScheirer commented, this combination will also work:

```
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@"])
xy = (206901.75, 5997594.47)
```

while this does not:

```
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@"])
xy = arcpy.Point(206901.75, 5997594.47)
```

but this should:

```
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@"])
xy = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(206901.75, 5997594.47))
```

Comment: `SHAPE@` would work too then.

Comment: Now `arcpy.Point(206901.75, 5997594.47)` should be `arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(206901.75, 5997594.47))`

Comment: For those who are wondering about the meaning of `SHAPE@`, `SHAPE@XY` : http://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/insertcursor-class.htm